# How can I use php google client with proxy

Tags: php, proxy, config, google-client

Is there any possibility to use the latest php google client with proxy?

I'm asking because in my company we started using proxy for all our web apps, and I can't find any simple solution for that :)

Any advice, suggestions?

Comment: I believe the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049352/google-api-php-client-library

Comment: Yes but in that answer sugests to modify original code :(

Answer (score 3):

I think it is the simplest solution:

```
$c = new Google_Client();
$c->setSc opes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'));

// set proxy config for curl IO in development enviroment
if(APPLICATION_ENV != "production") {
  $io = new Google_IO_Curl($c);
  $curloptions = array();
  $curloptions[CURLOPT_PROXY] = "proxy-host:3128";
  $io->setOptions($curloptions);
  $c->setIo($io);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be late! But may help someone!

You can set http client like this:

```
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['timeout' => 5, 'proxy' => 'localhost:8000']);
$googleClient->setHttpClient($httpClient);
```

See this for more information:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#controlling-http-client-configuration-directly

Answer (score 1):

Use as in Guzzle:

```
$google_client = new Google_Client(['proxy' => '185.84.36.240:8080']);
```